How to Manage a Local APT Package Mirror with Custom Tags Using Debtags
Seeking Advice: Managing a Local APT Package Mirror with Custom Tags
Hello everyone,
I'm looking for some advice and best practices on managing a local APT package mirror with custom tags. Here's the scenario I'm working with:
The Goal
I have set up the local APT mirror using apt-mirror, and it works fine for me.
But I need to organize the packages on my local APT mirror with custom tags, allowing client machines to install packages based on these tags. I came across the debtags tool, which seems to allow for the manual addition of tags to packages. However, I'm open to other suggestions or methods that might be more efficient or easier to manage.
Questions

Has anyone implemented a similar setup using debtags? If so, how did
it work out for you?

Are there any other tools or methods that you would recommend for
managing package tags and installations?

How do you handle distributing tag information to multiple client
machines efficiently?

Any tips on automating this process to reduce manual work?



I've used Aptly to manage apt package repositories.  Both local mirrors of public distro repos, and local repos that held only my team's custom-built packages.  AFAIK, Aptly supports tags, though you should check the docs to make sure it works exactly the way you want.
The job where I first used Aptly was previously using Artifactory to mirror our distro's public repos, but we ran into some unwanted behavior when we tried to freeze our local mirror.  That was 5-6 years ago, so the functionality may have changed.  Without that quirk, Artifactory was a good mirror, though it was on the network rather than the local mirror you asked for.  I don't know what kind of tag support Artifactory has, but the docs should be able to tell you.
